# How to get array, which contains different types of variable?

Tags: php, arrays, attachment

I've tried to create the dynamic form for send resume. I have created html table with inputs fields. There's my html code form:

```
            <form  action="index.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Qualification</th>
                    <th>Year of end</th>
                    <th>Form</th>
                    <th>Document</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="EducationPlaces">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name='edrow[]'  type='text' class='form-control' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name='edrow[]' type='text' class='form-control' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name='edrow[]' type='text' class='form-control' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name='edrow[]' type='text' class='form-control' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name='edrow[]' type='file' class='form-control' />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save_file">
            <br>
        </form> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addEducationRow()"> Add row </button>
```

For dynamic creating rows into once table i use next code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function addEducationRow()
    {
        $("<tr> " +
            "<td>" +
            "<input name='edrow[]' type='text' class='form-control' />" +
            "</td> " +
            "<td>" +
            "<input name='edrow[]' type='text' class='form-control' />" +
            "</td> " +
            "</td> " +
            "<td>" +
            "<input name='edrow[]' type='text' class='form-control' />" +
            "</td> " +
            "</td> " +
            "<td>" +
            "<input name='edrow[]' type='text' class='form-control' />" +
            "</td> " +
            "<td>" +
            "<input name='edrow[]' type='file' class='form-control' />" +
            "</td> " +
            "</tr>").appendTo('.EducationPlaces');
    }
</script>
```

I can get data as array use something like this:
 `$myArray=$_POST['edrow']`
but so i can get only text data and can't get attachments.

For attachments I can use next code:

```
$file_aray=$_FILES['file'];
```

Eventually there will be two different arrays, and I don't know how to get one array which will be contain all data from my table.

Could you show me right way to solve my problem?

Comment: $_FILES is for files ... $_POST is for $_POST data .. just do this `$dataArray = array($_FILES, $_POST);` ...

Comment: You better don't put file uploads in the same form with regular data. Create a separate page for file uploads.